# How can i get access token from Twitter?

Tags: iphone, twitter, authentication

I have created titter login in my iphone application,here i want to send my access token and secret key to server for auto sharing functionality, i can't get my access token and sekret key ,please help me out thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
ACAccountType *twitterType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType
                 withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){

                     if(!granted){
                         NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
                     }
                     NSLog(@"store %@",store);
                 }];
if([[store accounts] count] > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"TWEET");
    self.hasTwitterAccountAccess = YES;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"newlog");
    self.hasTwitterAccountAccess = NO;
}


if(self.hasTwitterAccountAccess){
    NSLog(@"login");
    // If we have twitter access, refresh the table view
    ACAccountType *twitterType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Reverse OAuth: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth